# FocusedElement of context menu in RadDataBoundListBox is always getting null

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik, mvvmcross

I using RadDataBoundListBox in mvvmcross WP app. I using Pivot for tabs, previously I have one viewmodel for all pivot item but now created child view models for all pivot items. Since I use DataContext property for child view model binding but getting problem to RadContextMenu. when "Opening" event fire of context menu then FocusedElement getting null and no Command working.

tappedItem is always null in this line.

RadDataBoundListBoxItem tappedItem = e.FocusedElement as Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBoxItem;

This is my code :

- test.xaml file :

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="uiPivot" Title="{Binding HeaderTitle}">

        <!-- Tab 1 -->
        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="uiPivotTicketDetails" Header="ticket details" DataContext="{Binding TicketEditVM}">
       <!-- Some Code -->

        </phone:PivotItem>

       <!-- Tab 2-->
        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="uiPivotTimeEntry" DataContext="{Binding TicketTimeEntryVM}" >
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <telerik:RadImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding CmdTimeEntryAdd}" ButtonShape="Ellipse" RestStateImageSource="/Assets/Images/Add-New.png"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="time entries" />                

                </StackPanel>

            </phone:PivotItem.Header>

            <telerik:RadDataBoundListBox x:Name="uiTimeEntryList" ItemsSource="{Binding TicketTimeEntries}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimeEntryItemTemplate}" EmptyContent="There are no time entries to display">

                <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu OpenGesture="Hold" Opening="uiTicketTimeEntryMenu_Opening" >
                        <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenuItem Content="edit" Tap="onTicketTimeEntryEdit_Tap"  />
                        <telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenuItem Content="delete" Tap="onTicketTimeEntryDelete_Tap" />
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>

            </telerik:RadDataBoundListBox>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Here is Test.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class TicketEditHomeView : MvxPhonePage
{
   public TicketEditHomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the Context menu...

        RadContextMenu.SetFocusedElementType(this.uiTimeEntryList, typeof(RadDataBoundListBox));
     }


    private void uiTicketTimeEntryMenu_Opening(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuOpeningEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // This tktTappedItem is getting null
            RadDataBoundListBoxItem tktTappedItem = e.FocusedElement as Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadDataBoundListBoxItem;
            if (tktTappedItem != null)
            {
                ticketTimeEntryDataContext = tktTappedItem.DataContext;
            }


            if (tktTappedItem == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if (tktTappedItem != null)
            {
                tktTappedItem = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void onTicketTimeEntryEdit_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.TicketTimeEntryVM.CmdTimeEntrySelected.Execute(ticketTimeEntryDataContext);
    }

    private void onTicketTimeEntryDelete_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.TicketTimeEntryVM.CmdTimeEntryDeleted.Execute(ticketTimeEntryDataContext);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-I figured out where i am going wrong. While setting focused element type in constructor i am using RadDataBoundListBox instead of RadDataBoundListBoxItem.

Here is right code :

```
 public TicketEditHomeView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set the Context menu...

    RadContextMenu.SetFocusedElementType(this.uiTimeEntryList, typeof(RadDataBoundListBoxItem));
 }
```